# How to use Python to execute complex CURL command for InfluxDB

Tags: python, curl

Could I anyone explain how I can use requests in Python to send this CURL:

```
curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb' --data-binary 'cpu_load_short,host=server01,region=us-west value=0.64 1434055562000000000'
```

I dont know how to parse it into a sample code. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061227/curl-vs-python-requests-when-hitting-apis - duplicate. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797455/how-to-use-requests-python-module-to-make-curl-calls

Comment: That doesn't help, as it still doesn't cldearly show how to do it for this.

Answer (score 4):

```
import requests

url_string = 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb'
data_string = 'cpu_load_short,host=server01,region=us-west value=0.64 1434055562000000000'

r = requests.post(url_string, data=data_string)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked well.  What if we want to do this:  curl -i -XPOST http://localhost:8086/query --data-urlencode "q=CREATE DATABASE mydb"

Answer (score 0):

To create a InfluxDB via Python3:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import urllib.request as requests

url = "http://localhost:8086/query"

params = {
"q=CREATE DATABASE mydb"
}

r = requests.Request(url, data=params)
```